# How can I use Render sub-template in a C# template in a Content module that uses lists within lists?

Tags: razor, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

2SXC 10.25.2 / DNN 9.3.2

I have a 2sxc module that uses a C# template with "list" enabled. I have a content type called "pathway" and inside that I have 2 entity picker fields for "first step sessions" and then "next step sessions". These entity pickers use a "session" content type. Inside each of those "session" content types I also have an entity picker for "speaker(s)". All in all, it's a setup that I have lists within lists within lists.

When I create the loops for each of the sublists, I can easily do that within the 1 C# template but it becomes repetitive, long, and unruly because there's so much c# code where I'm looping the same session template for different entity picker sections. So, I tried using the "Render sub-template" code to simplify the template - I created new sub templates and inserted them in - it seemed to work at first, however, the template started outputting all "session" items into each item in the list.

I suspect that the subtemplate somehow loses the context of the item that it's in so it's outputting everything. Is there something special I need to know about using subtemplates with for each loops? Do I have to include params and, if so, how do I do that?

**EDIT to include code sample:**

Here is a small, simplified version of the code I'm working with:

```
@foreach(var Content in AsList(Data)) {
<h2>@Content.Title</h2>
    
    <h3>Lead Sessions</h3>
    
    <div class="lead-sessions text-green">
        @foreach(var item in AsList(Content.LeadSessions as object)){
            <h4>@item.LeadSessionTitle</h4>
            <p>@item.LeadSessionText</p>
        }
    </div>    
        
    <h3>Next Sessions</h3>
    <div class="next-sessions text-green">
        @foreach(var nextitem in AsList(Content.NextSessions as object)){
            <h4>@nextitem.LeadSessionTitle</h4>
            <p>@nextitem.LeadSessionText</p>
        }
    </div>
}
```

I want to make a subtemplate so I don't have to repeat the same code for the sessions loop. How could I simplify this template to use a subtemplate for looping the sessions within the lead-sessions and next-sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the modified question, it's a bit like this

```
@foreach(var Content in AsList(Data)) {
    <h2>@Content.Title</h2>
    
    <h3>Lead Sessions</h3>
    @RenderPage("_inner.cshtml", new { Items = Content.LeadSessions })
        
    <h3>Next Sessions</h3>
    @RenderPage("_inner.cshtml", new { Items = Content.NextSessions })
}
```

Second file `_inner.cshtml`

```
@{
  var items = AsList(PageData["Items"]);
}
<div class="next-sessions text-green">
    @foreach(var nextitem in items){
        <h4>@nextitem.LeadSessionTitle</h4>
        <p>@nextitem.LeadSessionText</p>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can just use `RenderPage` without params, or pass in params like in the blog app:

```
@RenderPage("shared/_Category Filter.cshtml", new { MobileView = true, FilteredCategory = filteredCategory })
```

See https://github.com/2sic/app-blog/blob/master/_List.cshtml#L25

Then the template can retrieve the values like

```
@{
  var filteredCategory = PageData["FilteredCategory"];
}
```

See https://github.com/2sic/app-blog/blob/master/shared/_Category%20Filter.cshtml#L6

You can pass around any amount of values/objects like this.

You can also create helpers - and then call those helpers. Like this

https://github.com/2sic/app-news/blob/master/shared/_Helpers.cshtml#L24-L33

Comment: I'll try these examples next time.

Comment: best mark as solved for other people looking for this :)

Comment: Knowing that I have a content type called "Learning Pathway" that has two entity picker fields for "Lead Sessions" and "Next Sessions", where the subtemplate for these are the same but are only differentiated by the parent tag, how would I set up the params to make sure that the Lead and Next sessions are only showing for that learning pathway?

Comment: I edited my original post with some sample code and clarification.